# GMSL cameras connection

Tags: camera

I've been looking for some cameras for robotics purposes. With lots of vendors now coming out with (Maxim serialised) GMSL cameras (e.g. Zed X, Realsense D457) - I'm wondering why it's so hard/expensive to simply connect it to a computer and get a working video/image out of it.

From my very limited understanding, it seems that many of these cameras stream the raw (e.g. Bayer) sensor readings directly across the GMSL connection, so it relies on the usually Nvidia Jetson-based computer to process the raw reading into a usable image through its ISP - so one needs a GMSL receiver board that converts GMSL to e.g. CSI to connect to the Jetson. From what I can see; these boards contain just the GMSL Maxim deserialiser to decode the serialised signal, and then to CSI to connect to the Jetson. However, what I'm confused about is why these receiver boards seem so outrageously expensive; sometimes even more expensive than the device. e.g.:

https://store.stereolabs.com/products/gmsl2-adapter ($400, supports 2-4 cameras)

https://store.intelrealsense.com/buy-intel-realsense-des457.html ($842!, seems to support 2 realsenses)

Furthermore, you are now limited to only using computers that are supported by these boards.

Please correct me if I'm wrong:

1. It seems to me that the main selling point of GMSL is that the cables can go up to 15m. With so much added cost to just connect the camera to a computer, and severely limiting your selection of computers, is there any good reason to look at these GMSL cameras if one does not need to run cameras very far? Is it better to just stick to simple USB/GigE cameras for most ~1m cable length use cases, unless it's for e.g. ADAS systems in cars?
2. Searching online for GMSL (PCIe) frame grabbers, it seems that manufacturers like stuffing a whole Jetson Xavier NX inside the frame grabber card, which I find very interesting (in terms of the effect on cost) ... Is the Jetson simply there to provide ISP capabilities? Since I expect the Maxim deserialiser chip to be doing all the required deserialiser compute work...
3. Some of these GMSL cameras do have an onboard ISP, and they state that their deserialised output would be in a usable image form e.g. RGB, YUV. Are there any (hopefully affordable, since it doesn't require an ISP anymore) GMSL receiver boards one could purchase to connect such a camera to their computer (preferably via USB or CSI, but PCIe or GigE are fine too)?
4. Must I also check whether the GMSL receiver expects raw sensor frames vs already processed frames or are they incompatible with one another? For example, I've found one GMSL to USB at http://www.hansesolutions.com/project/hs-uc/ with the claim of "Plug and play", but I have no idea whether it will actually work with a camera that outputs raw sensor vs already processed images.
5. Are there any easily purchasable boards online (e.g. from Mouser?). I've been trying to search for a board that can take 3-4 GMSL cameras, to connect to a Jetson device. However, I find that many camera boards state that they are only compatible with a certain Jetson carrier board AND cameras from a certain brand - such as https://connecttech.com/product/rogue-e-con-gmsl2-camera-board/ which seems to indicate that it is only compatible e-con cameras and the Rogue carrier board - Is the only hope to look for a customised solution?